# Jit a JAX function that select a function from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements, jit, jax

I have a JAX function that, given the order and the index, selects a polynomial from a pre-defined dictionary, as follows:

```
poly_dict = {
    (0, 0): lambda x, y, z: 1.,
    (1, 0): lambda x, y, z: x,
    (1, 1): lambda x, y, z: y,
    (1, 2): lambda x, y, z: z,
    (2, 0): lambda x, y, z: x*x,
    (2, 1): lambda x, y, z: y*y,
    (2, 2): lambda x, y, z: z*z,
    (2, 3): lambda x, y, z: x*y,
    (2, 4): lambda x, y, z: y*z,
    (2, 5): lambda x, y, z: z*x
}

def poly_func(order: int, index: int):
    
    try:
        return poly_dict[(order, index)]
    
    except KeyError:
        print("(order, index) must be a key in poly_dict!")
        return
```

Now I want to jit `poly_func()`, but it gives an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DynamicJaxprTracer'` Moreover, if I just do

```
def poly_func(order: int, index: int):
    
    return poly_dict[(order, index)]
```

it still gives the same error. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your approach: first, traced values cannot be used to index into Python collections like dicts or lists. Second, JIT-compiled functions can only return array values, not functions.

With that in mind, it is impossible to make the function you propose work with JAX transforms like JIT. But you could modify your approach to use a list rather than a dict of functions, and then use [`lax.switch`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.switch.html) to dynamically select which function you call. Here's how it might look:

```py
def get_index(order, index):
  return order * 5 + index

poly_list = 16 * [lambda x, y, z: 0.0]  # place-holder function

for key, val in poly_dict.items():
  poly_list[get_index(*key)] = poly_dict[key]


def eval_poly_func(order: int, index: int, args):
  ind = get_index(order, index)
  return jax.lax.switch(ind, poly_list, *args)

result = jax.jit(eval_poly_func)(2, 0, (5.0, 6.0, 7.0))
print(result)
# 25.0
```

Comment: do you know if there is a way to use jax.lax.switch or something similar that merely returns the relevant function from the list but does not need to evaluate it? I want to pull the function from a list given its index but do not want to evaluate it yet (this function will get passed to another function)

Comment: also, why can traced values of jitted functions not be used to index into python dicts/lists?

Comment: No, there's no way to select a function from a list/dict using a traced index/key without evaluating it (using e.g. `switch`). Traced values cannot index into Python dicts/lists because traced values are abstract representations of every possible integer, so by definition it's impossible to know which entry from the dict/list to return.

Comment: Thanks! What about selecting a number from a 1D jax.numpy.array of integers using an index that is an input to a jax-jitted function aka using a traced value?

Comment: Sure, that works fine, because Jax array indexing is done at runtime, not at trace-time. Python lists and dicts are only accessible at trace-time, so they cannot be indexed with runtime-only (traced) values.