# How to rewrite this JAX snippet to prevent TypeError: unhashable type: 'DynamicJaxprTracer'?

Tags: python, jit, jax

I am rewriting some Python code in JAX with the goal of speeding it up using jax.jit. There is a part of my old code where I have a dict that maps some integer to a list of functions. Every integer has a unique list of functions assigned to it. The functions are all JAX compatible, but the problem is my use case. I have a master function whose arguments are the number to be fed into these functions and the integer that tells me which list of functions to grab from the dict.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate what I mean:

```py
from jax import jit

# set up a dict that maps integers to a list of functions
test_dict = {1122997037:[lambda x: x**2, lambda x: 2*x],
             1124279607:[lambda x: x**3, lambda x: 3*x]}
             
@jit
def evaluate_functions(xval,index):
    """ index can be assumed to be one of the keys of test_dict """ 
    
    # given the input index, pull the relevant list of functions from test_dict
    func1, func2 = test_dict[index]
    
    # evaluate both functions at the input xval and return values
    return func1(xval), func2(xval)


print(evaluate_functions(2,1122997037))
print(evaluate_functions(2,1124279607))
```

If you remove the @jit decorator, it works as expected and prints (4,4) and (8,6). But with the @jit decorator, it raises the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[60], line 16
     11     f1, f2 = test_dict[index]
     13     return f1(xval), f2(xval)
---> 16 print(evaluate_functions(2,1))
     17 print(evaluate_functions(2,2))

    [... skipping hidden 12 frame]

Cell In[60], line 11, in evaluate_functions(xval, index)
      7 @jit
      8 def evaluate_functions(xval,index):
      9     """ index can be assumed to be one of the keys of test_dict """ 
---> 11     f1, f2 = test_dict[index]
     13     return f1(xval), f2(xval)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'DynamicJaxprTracer'
```

**Is there any way to rewrite this to make it work with @jit? For example using jax.lax.switch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The problem with this is that you can't do conditional code execution in JAX based on input data</strike> (Edit: I was mistaken about the semantics of `lax.cond`). You could mark the `index` argument as static, which means that JAX will recompile the function each time a new value of it is used:

```py
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=1)
def evaluate_functions(xval,index):
    ...
```

This is the sort of compilation behavior you'll see:

```py
evaluate_functions(0, 0) # JIT runs, may be slow
evaluate_functions(1, 0) # No compilation, fast 
evaluate_functions(1, 3) # JIT runs again
evaluate_functions(7, 3) # No compilation
# etc
```

This is a good solution if you'll be using each of the functions many times. If there's a large number of functions and you'll only be using each one once this won't help you.

Edit:
Here's a solution using jax.lax.switch, I'm not sure how the performance will be:

```py
keys, branches = zip(*test_dict.items())    
branches1, branches2 = zip(*branches)    
    
@jit    
def evaluate_functions(xval,index):    
    """ index can be assumed to be one of the keys of test_dict """·    
    ind_to_key = jnp.asarray(keys)    
    
    ind = jnp.where(ind_to_key == index, size=1)[0][0]    
    out1 = jax.lax.switch(ind, branches1, xval)                                                                               
    out2 = jax.lax.switch(ind, branches2, xval)                                                                               
    return out1, out2
```

Comment: Hmm... yeah I'll only be using each list of functions (corresponding to one key of test_dict) only once... I'm surprised there's no way around this with jax.lax.switch or something.

Comment: I added in a solution which uses switch, but I don't have a lot of experience with it so I'm not sure how performant it will be. In my benchmarking with an example of using a single function with and without switch there was a pretty significant slow-down.

Comment: What about converting my test_dict to a list of lists of functions and then using jax.lax.switch as was proposed by @jakevdp here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191616/jit-a-jax-function-that-select-a-function-from-a-dictionary/76192101#76192101 ? The keys of my test_dict are huge integers but perhaps if I can assume order is preserved in the mapping between test_dict.keys() and the list of lists of functions we construct from test_dict.values() then maybe there is a way to make this work with jax.lax.switch?

Comment: P.S. Looks like I posted a response and you added the edit at the same time! I'll take a look.

Comment: @JimRaynor Let me know how it works for you, I'm curious how the compile time scales with the number of branches.

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- finally confirming that using jax.lax.switch within my code worked for me. It adds a negligible overhead given the runtime of the rest of my code. Thanks for the help!